# Kotlin List reverse

Tags: kotlin, reverse

Есть вопрос по Котлин. Не могу разобраться.
Есть строка с делиметром \n
Задача - простая, как 5 копеек - сделать реверс частей строки.

Я строку через .split("\n") загнал в List

```
val s = "abcd\nefgh\nijkl\nmnop"
var listStrings: List<String> = s.split("\\n")
```

Делаю reversed() и никаких изменений.

```
println("$listStrings")
listStrings.reversed()
println("$listStrings")
```

Не сдаюсь, использую брутфорс))
.asReversed(), Collections.reverse(listStrings) -> ни в какую. Никаких изменений. Даже если переделать в Mutable List

Хорошо. Попробуем поэкспериментировать.

```
var listStrings2: List<String> = listOf("Hello", "World")
println("$listStrings2") //[Hello, World]
Collections.reverse(listStrings2)
println("$listStrings2") //[World, Hello]
```

Все работает.
Кто может объяснить, в чем разница между этими двумя листами ? Задача простая до безобразия, какой-то ступор (

Заранее прошу прощения за тупой вопрос. Прошу не минусовать. Помогите разобраться !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых `split("\n")`

Во-вторых `reversed` и все методы `-ed` возвращают новый лист

```
val reversedList = listStrings.reversed()
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас ! Получается было 2 проблемы... Очень благодарю за Вашу внимательность и за возврат нового листа !